# MXML syntax for "inline" functions

Tags: apache-flex, mxml

Somewhere in the internets I stumbled across some kind of inline function for setting the color of a label.

Something like this:

```
color="{data >0 ? 0x006600 : 0xFF0000}
```

Basically, this is exactly what I need in my ItemRenderer, but in an if-else if-else way.

The script above says data > 0 then set color to green, else set it to red. What I need is an additional case, that is no change set color to gray.

Is that accomplishable with this sort of "inline" function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
data==null ? 0xCCCCCC : (data>0 ? 0x006600 : 0xFF0000)
```

But what's the underlying goal?  You might be better off with a style function.

Comment: The goal is to update the color according to the incoming values. Data has in fact two properties, newValue and oldValue that get updated frequently (using binding). What I need is to change the colors of the labels (well to be exact the background color of my skin class, but lets start simple ;)) according to the values of the properties. It is actually a little more complex, so a style function would probably be the way to go, I'm just not sure how such a function would work in an item render with data objects that change.

Comment: It wouldn't be *in* the item renderer, and that's the point...since it is external to the renderer, it can be easily changed without changing your renderer. In Flex 3, you can do something like http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/search/label/DataGrid . In either Flex 3 or 4, you can use a ClassFactory to create a renderer with a property that you can populate with a callback function that determines the style. The issue with that is that you then have to handle when it gets called, whereas styleFunction on a TileList or DataGrid just works.

Answer (score 1):

It is called ternary operator, and it's great to clarify small conditional statements. But it's generally not recommended to nest ternary statements...

Comment: If you want to go that route, it's also generally better practice to avoid conditionals as much as possible http://www.antiifcampaign.com/.